# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getZoom' of undefined

Tags: google-maps

I am new to Google Map , so please excuse if this a dumb question .

I am trying to Use Marker Cluster Option with Google Maps

This is my code

```
var map;
var global_markers = [];
var markers = [
    [37.09024, -95.712891, 'trialhead0'],
    [37.09024, -95.712891, 'trialhead1'],
    [37.09024, -95.712892, 'trialhead2']
];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.77627, -73.910965);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    addMarker();
}

function addMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        // obtain the attribues of each marker
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
        var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + " | Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
        });
        marker['infowindow'] = contentString;
        global_markers[i] = marker;
        global_markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, global_markers);
window.onload = initialize;
```

When i run this code , i am getting the following exception under browser console

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getZoom' of undefined**

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuTg/1023/

How to resolve this ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` is only instantiated in in the window onload handler, but it is passed to `MarkerCluster` constructor as an argument *before* it. That's why it's undefined.

Make sure `MarkerCluster` is constructed after `map`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuTg/1025/

Comment: Thank you very much , when i clcik on Marker Icon , how can i display 3 icons ??

Comment: Please ask that in a new question and show your attempts to get the desired result.

Comment: no dont mind , i observed that when i chnaged the coordinates little bit they showed as showin in this fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuTg/1026/ , but i am thinking how can i handle that programaticlally